# Can PDO::FETCH_CLASS mode be used for one row (not fetchAll)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I feel a little dirty asking this here, since I feel I should've just been able to Google it, but well... I didn't find anything.

Is there a way to use the fetchmode `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` in the normal `fetch` function?
I want to retrieve a single row, so using `fetchAll` is out of the question (performance issues).

I know I could use `setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "MyClass")`, but ideally I would prefer not to change the default fetch mode. I realise that I could always manually set it back to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` afterwards, but it's not quite as neat as I'd like (extra function calls, code clutter, etc.).

If it isn't possible or the extra function calls don't matter at all that is fine too. I was just wondering since it seems such an obvious thing to want to do.

P.S. `PDO::fetch()` does seem to accept `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` as it's first argument, but I can't find a way to pass the class-identifier string in...

Comment: You need to call `setFetchMode()` to specify the class name. I don't think there's a way around that since `PDOStatement::fetch()` doesn't have a `$fetch_argument` property like `fetchAll()` does.  Why doesn't it? I don't know; it makes for an odd API incompatibility.

Comment: Yes, this is what I unfortunately expected. Ah well, it's not a problem, but it makes for slightly less readable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be no. No there is no such function.

Use either `setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "MyClass")` with your statement, or use `fetchAll((PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "MyClass")`.